# Newsletter image over image

Tags: css, image, html-email, mailchimp, email-templates

can anyone help me with my problem? I try to build newsletter with couple table segments because mailchimp have problem with code and break my mail content if he is not in the table. Main problem for me is image over image. Please, take a look at my code.

Pattern is bottom image and have 100% size (700x50px) and logo is top image (32x32px). Logo must to be on right side and over pattern image with margin-top -20px and margin-right 30px but without using "position" property (mailchimp break all position property).

Right now, my logo is under pattern. I was try to fix this problem with z-index but nothing happens here.

```
<table class="header_class">
<td>
<img class="pattern_header"src="pattern.jpg" alt="pattern" />
<img class="logo_small"src="logo.jpg" alt="logo" align="right"/>
<h1>July 2017</h1>
</td>
</table>
```

my css:

```
pattern_header{
max-width: 700px;
}

logo_small{

margin-right: 30px;
margin-top: -20px;
}
```

(I am totally beginner and maybe my code isn't ok)

What the header should look like:

[image]

Comment: Did the solution work for you?

Answer (score 1):

For background to work on emails you can use positions (as you have found out). For backgrounds to work in Outlook you need to use VML (vector markup language), this is native to outlook (>2007). All the rest of the email clients should be able to read the background declaration on the td.

Few things to note in the below code:

- I have added `[HEIGHT OF IMAGE]` where you need to add the height for the VML.
- You have not provided image dimensions which you will need for logo. Note Outlook doesnt read style attributes on images.

```html
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td background="https://i.stack.imgur.com/UX7Jw.png" style=" background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/UX7Jw.png);background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/UX7Jw.png);">
        
         <!--[if gte mso 9]>
      <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:700px;height:159;">
        <v:fill type="frame" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/UX7Jw.png" color="#e9e9e9" />
        <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
      <![endif]--> 

    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        
        <td align="right" valign="top" style="padding:30px 30px 30px 0px;"><img class="logo_small" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/164VA.png" alt="logo" align="right"/></td>
      </tr>
    </table>


    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
        </v:textbox>
      </v:rect>
      <![endif]-->
        
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Now, logo is over pattern image and that's what I want but when I try to moving logo down with margin property my background also moving down. Logo must be separated object.

Comment: Use padding (not margin) on the td's that contain the h1 and the logo. See my edit above. See my example above.

Comment: I have updated my code with what your requirement was. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I need. Logo alignment is not to the top (offset from top 20px and from right 30px). Pattern alignment is top.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plziK.jpg)

Comment: this is a place for answers. I suggest you remove this and place it as a comment under my answer. People are quick to down vote or flag things like this.